# Proof of Lie theorem on solvable Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading a book of Helgason.

As you know, solvable Lie algebra $g \subset V= {\bf C}^n$ have a nonzero $v$ such that 
 $v$ is an eigenvector of any element of $g$.

I can follow the proof in the book. But the next corollary is : Under the above assumption, $g$ is a set of upper triangular matrices in some basis.

I have a difficulty to prove this.

How can we prove this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use induction on the dimension. Take $v \in V$ fixed by $g,$ and then consider the action of $g$ on the quotient space $V/{\rm span}(v).$

Comment: The corollary should be that «$g$ is **a** set of upper triangular matrices», not **the** set thereof.